# How about the speed of scikit-learn HMM compared with HTK?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hidden-markov-models, htk

I'm doing scene text recognition with HMM. I'm doubt of the speed of scikit-learn HMM code for training and predicting compared with HTK, for sklearn HMM is written in Python.

My data is really huge (tens of gigabytes), so speed is a critical problem.

Hope someone could share some experience.

Answer (score 2):

The sklearn implementation of HMM has been externalized as: https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn

There is also: https://github.com/jmschrei/yahmm

I don't know which is faster nor if they can compare with HTK.